# It seems the semicolon is sometimes optional in the WebForms View Engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Why do I need a semicolon to end a

```
<% Html.BeginForm(); %>
```

but not need a semicolon when ending a

```
<%= Html.TextBox("Name") %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first example is calling an Html extension method, which has the side effect of writing out content.

Your second example is using `=`, which is short-hand for `Response.Write()`. The `.TextBox()` does NOT have the side effect of writing into the Response, so you have to do it manually with the `=`.

Answer (score 1):

Code blocks can have many lines of code, so the semicolons are needed.

```
<% Html.BeginForm();
   DoSomeThingElse();
%>
```

When you use `<%= %>` you are evaluating a single statement and outputting the result.